# Create swipe-able cell menu for only certain cells

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have the following layout for my table view of two different kinds of cells: ContactCells and DropDownCells.  I want there to be a way to swipe to the side and get more options like the following picture, but only for DropDownCells, not ContactCells

[image: Slide gesture menu]

Then closest solution I have so far is the code below, but it only creates swipe menus for all cells not just the DropDownCells:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let moreRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "More", handler:{action, indexpath in
        print("MORE•ACTION");
    });
    moreRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.851, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0);

    let deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete", handler:{action, indexpath in
        print("DELETE•ACTION");
    });

    return [deleteRowAction, moreRowAction];
}
```

Comment: Use the same logic you use in CellForRow() when deciding which cell type to use. Paste your CellForRow() and I'll show you

Comment: @Shades In that logic I have to use `return cell` as the object returned, so how would I handle having to run `return [deleteRowAction, moreRowAction]`

Comment: The return statement is not the logic, the logic is what happens earlier that determines which cell type to use.

Comment: @Shades regardless, I still need to both return the cell and `deleteRowAction, moreRowAction`.  How would I be able to accomplish this